# Load tensorflow (keras) model on Flask server under mod_wsgi

Tags: python, tensorflow, flask, flask-restful

I have created a Flask sever which run tensorflow as service. Now I want to deploy the system and I try to use the mod_wsgi in apache2.
The setup of the Flask server in apache2 works well.

In my first edition of my Flask sever I used the `if __name__ == '__main__':` to preload the tensorflow model. Like this:

my_app.py

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, "/var/www/python_servers/theserver")

import tensorflow as tf
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

the_model = None
model_path = 'nn/mymodel'


def load_model():
    global the_model
    the_model = tf.keras.models.load_model(model_path)


def prepare_image(image, target):
    if image.mode != "RGB":
        image = image.convert("RGB")

    image = image.resize(target)
    image = img_to_array(image)
    image = np.expand_dims(image, axis=0)
    image /= 255.

    return image



@app.route("/predict", methods=["POST"])
def predict():

    if flask.request.method == "POST":
        if flask.request.files.get("file"):
            # read the image in PIL format
            image = flask.request.files["file"].read()
            image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(image))


            image = prepare_image(image, target=(299, 299))
            
            preds = predict_gretaste_dataset(image1)

    return flask.jsonify(preds)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    load_model()
    app.run(debug=True, use_debugger=False, use_reloader=False, host='0.0.0.0')
```

Now (under the mod_wsgi)  Ι have created a .wsgi file like this:

my_server.wsgi

```
#!/user/bin/python
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, "/var/www/python_servers/gretaste")

from my_app import app as application
```

The problem is that like the above example (mod_wsgi) the code under the `if __name__ == '__main__':` it is not executed in the start of the server so as to preload my model and to be ready for the `POST` requests.

I dont want in every `POST` request to reload my model. I want my model to be preloaded when the server is starting up.

Any idea??

Answer (score 0):

I think in the first run, it will take time to load the model. Then it will keep using global and it will not load it again. So the solution is to call the api for once after you start apache server.